# Is there any TypeScript AST explorer

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree

I need to explore the Abstract Syntax Tree of arbitrary TypeScript code, visually, without having to parse the code manually and read a JSON file or use a debugger.

Ideally, something similar to https://astexplorer.net/ but supporting TypeScript. Do you know any website implementing that?

Thanks

Comment: That's pretty cool, thank you for that. As for a typescript equivalent, there's the [Compiler API](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API) from which you can get an `AST`, but I've never heard of a visual representation for it.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [this tourguide](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to ask questions the right way and to learn more how stackoverflow works.

Comment: The AST explorer you linked (which is BTW awesome) has an option to parse with TypeScript :)

Comment: @SebastianSebald duh! It's my first question on stackoverflow and such a silly fail, lol! Anyways, it might be useful for others to know!

Comment: @yefremov https://astexplorer.net/  now has a typescript option in the dropdown just before `transform` toggle button.

Comment: This one is the best: https://ts-ast-viewer.com/ BTW this question is not off topic at all- I edited in the hope that https://stackoverflow.com/users/584192/samuel-liew reconsider open it.